# Store and iterate over result of query in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is my simple query in php, using mysqli object oriented style:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM usertable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$id= $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);

while($stmt->fetch()){
   echo $name." ";
}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

This works fine. I obtain the list of name retrieved from the select statement.

Now, inside the while I want use the `$name` variable as parameter for another query, but mysqli do not allow this, since I have to close the first query and then call the second query.

So I think I have to store the result of the first query and then iterate over the result calling a new query.

I have tried the following:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM usertable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$id= $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute();
//$stmt->bind_result($name);
$result = $stmt->store_result();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) 
{
    echo $row[0]." ";
}
```

But this does not work. The code inside while is never reached.

**N.B.**: I want avoid the use of `multi_query()`.

Comment: open another connection to the database and use that connection for the query in the while loop

Comment: @Linger, what if the connection variable is obtained using singleton pattern?

Comment: It sounds like you should simply use a JOIN to query all your data with a single query.

Comment: @Mike the second query maybe a INSERT or UPDATE, or some combination. Prbably I can to join all the query, but why I can't iterate over the result of first query?

Comment: *@Joseph82*, You should be able to open two different connection to the same database.  Use one connection for the initial query use the other connection when executing statement inside the while.  Try it and see if it works.

Comment: @linger The connection variable is getted using a function that return me a istance of mysqli object. I only know that the instance is always the same (Singleton is used). And the function that retrieve the connection is a black box.
Maybe I have to reformulate the question: is there a way for iterate  over the result of my first query after I have called $stmt->close()?

Comment: @Joseph82 You can insert/update across a join.  So if your need to iterate the select is simply to be able to insert/update multiple rows, you likely can still do this with a single query.  If you share your table schema information and a description of what you are actually trying to do, you will likely get suggestions on how best to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM usertable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$id= $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) 
{
    echo $row[0]." ";
}
```

Simply using `get_result()` and `fetch_array()`

Comment: get_result only works if you have the mysqlnd driver installed, otherwise, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 4):

[mysqli_stmt::store_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) return a boolean. According to the doc it should be something like:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->bind_result($name);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    //echo $name." ";
    // try another statement
    $query = "INSERT INTO usertable ...";
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    ...
}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

If this doesn't work you can fetch all rows first into an array and then looping that array again:

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
$names = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $names[] = $name;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

foreach($names as $name) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO usertable ...";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes @redreggae, you are right about store_result. It just return a boolean. But storing "manually" the result in an array seems a bit unorthodox.

Comment: your solution is usefull if is used a PHP version that does not support get_result()

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I myself like PDO more, because it is easier to use and supports different db's. So I really see no reason why to use mysqli.

Comment: Yes @redreggae, maybe PDO is a better alternative, in particoular for binding parameters. However I use only mysql database, so currently, migrating to PDO is not a priority. Surely in the future I will :)

Comment: @Joseph82 interestingly I did the same (execute an update statement inside a fetch loop) with PDO and MySql without problems. The only thing I can find in the docs regarding this problem is the following. `This method is useful for database drivers that do not support executing a PDOStatement object when a previously executed PDOStatement object still has unfetched rows...`. [PDOStatement::closeCursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php)

Comment: And I did NOT use `closeCursor`!