# Preparing SQL query with multiple parameters (mysqli)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I don't know why preparing this sql query is invalid.

```
$from = 1462890333;
$to = 1462890335;
$token = 123;
$sql = "SELECT temperature FROM `am_measurements` WHERE token = ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $token, $from, $to);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($a);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $a;
} else {
    echo "not good";
}
```

The result is "not good". How it should be done?

Here is the data from the am_measurements table:
https://mega.nz/#!tJEx0IiL!OoXHSVJh0A0kAVzYrcJKL6BGxktcZZWpOC26KV-Egao

@edit

Now I know what causes the problem but I don't know why and how to solve it:

```
$sensor_id = 0;
$from = 1462890333;
$to = 1462890335;

//MySQL Database Connect
include 'database.php';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT token FROM `am_sensors` WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $sensor_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($token);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $token; //this returns "123"
$sql = "SELECT temperature FROM `am_measurements` WHERE token = ? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $token, $from, $to);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($a);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo $a;
} else {
    echo "not good";
}
```

When I remove the previous sql query then everything is ok.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - and your `echo "not good";` doesn't help you.

Comment: I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));` (after else {) but the error message is empty.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` doesn't do much on its own except write to a file (check your logs).  Display them  `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and that belongs at the top of your script. what is `echo $a;` ?

Comment: also `ii` 2 i's for date? I doubt that... use all `s`'s here. Probably the reason why it's failing *silently*. values for `$from, $to` are what here? we need the db schema and values for the variables. I can't keep guessing here. oh never mind about my asking for the `$a` *lol* my mistake, you're binding the result.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is at the top, nothing changes. `$from` and `$to` contains a date in unix time.

Comment: I added values of the variables to the post.

Comment: How can I provide the db schema in the most convenient way for you?

Comment: include it in your question as to what those column types are and their lengths. Btw, try replacing your `$stmt->fetch(); echo $a;` with `while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo $a . "<br>" ;

}` I tested your code with success, so I don't know where it's going south  for you.

Comment: plus, `$from = 1462890333;
$to = 1462890335;` in order for your query to work, there would need to be one that is 1462890334 being "in between". My row values are 1462890335, 1462890331, 1462890334 and yielded all 3 rows in phpmyadmin also. Put this into phpmyadmin `SELECT temperature FROM am_measurements WHERE token = 123 AND date BETWEEN 1462890331 AND 1462890335` to see if anything shows up and make sure that all tokens are "123", otherwise it will fail.

Comment: The sql query in phpMyAdmin is working properly. I added PDF file with data from the am_measurements table.

Comment: I know what probably causes the problem. I updated my post.

Comment: try `store_result()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php after your first `execute()` This Q&A may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431425/store-and-iterate-over-result-of-query-in-mysqli

Comment: Adding `$stmt->free_result(); $stmt->close();` (from the Q&A you've linked) after first query helped. It looks like now everything works ;) Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of help. *Cheers*

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate; no harm done ;-)